# Iterating through an array of an object anglar2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm new to angular 2 and have a scenario where my service returns an object to my component and within the object there are a couple arrays.

One example is the 'phones' array.

In my view, I want to display each number in a list and I thought I could simple do the following:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" id="contact-list-item8" *ngFor="let phone of contact.phones">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
    <small>{{phone.phone_type}} phone</small>
    <br>
    <a href="tel:{{phone.phone_number}}">{{phone.phone_number}}</a>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble-outline"></i>
</ion-item>
```

I know the contact object is right, because I'm able to display other fields form the object, but for the *ngFor look, I get "Cannot read property 'phones' of undefined".

What am I missing here?

Comment: The safe navigation operator should solve your issue. If not, shout out :)

Comment: Damn he closed it before I could answer. Dude, just add `| async` after `contact.phones` in your ngFor.

Comment: Thanks, trichetriche!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the safe navigation operator in this case,

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" id="contact-list-item8" *ngFor="let phone of contact?.phones">
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. I keep forgetting about the async operator!

Comment: cool! mark if that helped